# Accessing SharePoint 2013 search object model from wcf, no result return

Tags: web-services, search-results

I am having a strange problem in accessing the SharePoint 2013 search object model.
I have a custom class, when the code is excuted in console application, it's works ok.
but in wcf, the return result always 0 result.

here is the main code:

```
    private int SearchTest(string siteUrl, string queryText, int rowLimit, int startRow, string loginUserName)
    {
        //get current user token
        SPUserToken curUserToken = GetUserTokenByUser(siteUrl, loginUserName);

        //using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl, curUserToken))
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
        {
            KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(site);

            keywordQuery.ResultsProvider = SearchProvider.Default;
            keywordQuery.QueryText = queryText;
            keywordQuery.RowLimit = rowLimit;
            keywordQuery.StartRow = startRow;

            SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor();
            ResultTableCollection resultTableCollection = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);

            var resultTables = resultTableCollection.Filter("TableType", KnownTableTypes.RelevantResults);

            var resultTable = resultTables.FirstOrDefault();
            //output result 
            return resultTable.TotalRows;
        }
    }
```

Any idea why is this happening?

the wcf service hosted in SharePoint, and call the wcf code as below:

```
SPSLamsServiceClient client = new SPSLamsServiceClient();

client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new NetworkCredential("userName", "password", "domain"); 

var search = client.Search(siteUrl, "test", 20, 0, "userloginname");
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are losing your impersonation context. Is the wcf service hosted in SharePoint?

Comment: yes, the wcf service hosted in SharePoint, and call the wcf code as below:

SPSServiceClient client = new SPSServiceClient();
            client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
            client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new NetworkCredential("userName", "password", "domain");